# Как управлять версиями NPM и NODE.JS

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

Здравствуйте.

**OS: Windows 10 PRO 64-bit, последние обновления.**

Что нужно поставить, чтобы управлять(переключать, обновлять и тд.) версиями node и npm отдельно.

Вначале поставил пакет `npm-windows-upgrade` он дает возможность менять версии npm, но не node.js. После поставил `nvm-windows` ситуация обратная, можно управлять node.js, но не `npm`. Вместе они не работают.

Какие программы или пакеты нужно установить для полного контроля над версиями `node` и `npm`

Comment: здесь все в подробностях https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: кстати у mpn нет контроля версиями...

Comment: Да я использую nvm4windows. Но он не дает менять версию npm, как это делает  npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: npm, есть разные...  у каждого проекта может быть свой...  когда ты устанавливаешь  hode себе на комп, он устанавливает    глобально свой минимальный npm пакет...   а потом ты для определенного проекта  формируешь себе такой npm локально такой пакет, который требуется для данного проекта...  у npm нет версии